# Recent Gecko / xulrunner / FireFox port for Delphi

Tags: delphi, firefox, lazarus, gecko

Asking a bit out of curiosity: Does anyone know about a recent port of Gecko (Firefox engine) for Delphi?

I'm currently using DCEF3 / TWebBrowser(IE) successfully and there's no need to change at the moment, but I'm curious to compare the browser performance (also feature-wise).

So far I've only found several different (or maybe related) older ports, where none turned out to be working with a recent Delphi version.

Of course I could translate the headers myself, but it won't make sense if there is anything out there that is already working.

For Lazarus there is [GeckoPort version2](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/GeckoPort_version2), but it seems to be quite old already (supports Gecko 10 / Firefox 10, released in Jan '12, already 3 years ago now). Does anyone know if a backport to Delphi is possible and/or if it's easy to update this to a recent version of Gecko?

In order to be more precise on the question: I would really like to use Gecko / XULrunner, so if no proper libraries are available, what are the steps for a port? It looks like there is no typical C API available that can be used for a straight forward port (from C to Pascal).

Would it be sufficient to translate the .idl files? If so, will an automated tool (like Embarcardero's idl2pas.jar) work?
At the moment I can't get the tool to run at all, but even if I would will it be possible to translate the IDL files (most probably in XPIDL format, similar to COBRA).

It seems possible to convert the files to XPCOM Type Library (.xpt), but will this be useful for a Delphi port?

Comment: I've tried porting `XULRunner`. However its quite a big project.. still in the works :)

Comment: Does that mean a library for this is close? Do you need help? What are the difficulties?

Comment: Just to offer you a different avenue: Some time ago (2007) I was working on an Internet Explorer's IInternetProtocol implementation, and it worked, so I started looking if the same was possible with FireFox, I found [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/d-gecko/) and got it to work on FireFox version 6, but Mozilla's rapid release schedule broke it and I couldn't keep up. I tried js-ctypes, which did something, but I gave up and concentrated on raw HTTP. [Look here](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/tree/master/Delphi/gecko) to look at the code.

Comment: @StijnSanders Your version is just too old. This is the newest [version](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0). More importantly why is this question on hold?

Comment: The question is on hold because of "off-topic". This is a question-and-answer site about programming problems, not a message board to ask for pointers for a suitable component/library/project, questions like that usually get cancelled.